# Suggestions for first time banned for time with subject to certain condition

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban, ban

I have seen many questions asking about being banned from asking questions. Certainly it's a great thing to punish the user who asks bad questions or doesn't know anything about computing.

There are many cases in which I have seen that users are waiting for a ban to be removed. Even me and other users don't read the FAQ first and start posting issues without knowing that the questions they are asking are of low quality and get banned easily.

The measures taken by Stack Overflow are very good, but I personally feel that the users who are first time registered loose and banned and lifting of a ban under certain conditions only, they might lose hope easily.

Here, I would like to suggest some features or certain conditions to be introduced regarding the re-activation of an account of first-time banned users:

1. The banned person must contact the support team at least one time asking for lifting of the ban and the moderator have the option to check if it's a first time ban or not.
2. The user must answer at least two questions asked by the community and both questions should be accepted by the creator of the question or by moderator.
3. I have also seen that there is no notification through email or other means which tells a user that he was banned from asking questions. It only comes to knowledge after clicking on "Ask Question". Creating a separate button/color box as red/yellow/green suggesting the ban's status. Red means 100% banned, yellow means he can be banned if the community downvote the questions and green means user can ask the questions.
4. The user asking to have the ban lifted must be an active member of community for at least six months (or any other decided period) and if then he can't remove the ban in that period, the next period's length would be doubled. Example: If I am banned from asking questions, all the measures would be taken within six months or the length of the ban would be increased to one year and if failed for the next one year then it will now increase to two years and so on and I have to do all the activities from starting point.
5. A first-time banned user have a separate area or tag or something where they can ask one question per month. If the question is accepted by the community by at least 10 votes i.e. the users who are not banned.
6. If a user have reviewed at least 100 questions accepted by a moderator, the process of cleaning of the post would gain pace, now which is done by only a few of the users.

These are my personal views and they are given to help the community.

Comment: To clarify - the core of what you are suggesting that there should be a specific set of rules *when* you get unbanned, as opposed to the way it is at the moment, where it's unclear when an unban will take place?

Comment: I suggest that the purpose of a ban is not to "punish" anyone, but to protect the site(s) from continuing poor content.

Comment: Yes, the purpose for banning is to protect the site from poor contents but I am only in favor/asking to cut down some rules only for the first time ban. If somebody is banned for first time to make little easy to lift the first time ban. The would be nice or website content management. How many persons from you maintaining multiple accounts on SO

Comment: I agree. Only two of my questions were slightly below standard while the rest were above standard, and I was question banned for over a week. That's a ridiculously long time for such a small offense.

Answer (score 6):

1. What does it matter if it's your first time or not? Just because you emailed, the ban should be lifted? All you have to do is get some upvotes on answers. Let's not fill the team's inbox.
2. This is already the way you get unbanned. You have to answer questions and get upvotes.
3. Why do you need a notification via email? Likely you'll just ignore it when you actually receive it because you're not interesting in posting a question at that time. Notifying them at the time of the question is much more efficient. Also, coloring buttons to account for a minority of users who *actually get question banned* isn't very helpful.
4. I'm confused what you're talking about here. Anyways, we're not here to get rid of you. We want you to contribute better content. Time has nothing to do with that, which is why question bans don't ever expire until you get upvotes on some answers.
5. What would motivate users to look at this tag? These people are question banned. Also, 10 votes is a lot. A large majority of questions don't ever reach 10 votes.
6. I'm not sure if users are blocked from suggesting edits when they're question banned. If they're not, then i'd encourage them to do so and let the community approve/reject them so they can build up some reputation.

Comment: 1. Emailing team means, he really want to get ban lifted there are many people who don't do single step.
2. Yes but to get unbanned 2 question are compulsory.
3. I am asking for first time also, Many people create account and ask question but didn't come back either

Comment: You've seen the amount of questions asked here regarding bans, right? I would not like to inflict that upon the team. I assume they have far better things to do with their time.

Comment: @animuson These are some conditions which are must to be fulfilled by user who are seeking lifting the ban, and only after completing all thing the ban would be lifted.